# Can a stopway withstand thrust of B737 engines on takeoff if the aircraft is lined up on the edge of the runway?

Tags: runways, thrust, damage

Can the thrust of Boeing 737-300 engines break the asphalt surface of a stopway marked with yellow chevrons? Can anyone give a documented reference?

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't withstand the thrust? Aircraft take off from the edge of the runway all the time.

Comment: As far as I know the yellow chevron asphalt is there _precisely_ to withstand jetwash.